# How to make a core of activity on android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am new to Android development. After learning from many tutorials I got many Activities and many Fragments. How can I make a core engine to check what Activity is running and what Fragment is showing on a container?

Assume that I have:

```
Acivity01, Activity02, ... , Activity10  

Fragment01, Fragment02, ... , Fragment10
```

I want to make a class that filters the Activity where Activity is on runtime and what Fragment is embeded to that activity.

How can I do this?

Comment: From what I understand you want to know what activity is running, right? Do you want a message from the device or through de console?

Comment: Yes, Kohakukun you are right. I have a class that extends to an application, that class will run an activity and from that activity user will trigger another activity and fragment embedded on it.  I want to make the core who managed this activity and fragment.  By The Way Thank's for for all respect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you may want to store some references within your Application class to an Activity and to Fragment instance(-s), which are currently in foreground (by this I mean that user can instantly interact with Activity/Fragment).

1. As for Activity
   Create some Activity field in your Application class and getter/setter methods for it (e.g., setCurrentActivity(), getCurrentActivity()). Then call setCurrentActivity() from onResume() method for each of your Activity instances. Don't forget to call setCurrentActivity, supplying null reference to ir in order to properly handle a case, when there are no foreground activities, but application is stll working.
2. As for Fragment
   The general idea is similar to the first item, but there can be more than one Fragment instance in foreground state at time. So you need to store something like List, where you add your resumed fragments and remove paused.

You may also want to implement something similar for dialogs, for example. Then use the same strategy. Hope it will help.

Comment: that a great QArea,  thank's for your answer i was create a class and named it BaseActivity that extends activity class and make method getter/setter as you said and it's work. so i can call getCurrentActivity() from other class that extends BaseActivity class.